# Fetch blob image from table and display it using php sqlite3

Tags: php, sqlite, blob

I know this question has been asked many times but I couldnot solve this using any of them.
I am new to sqlite and cannot understand what I am doing wrong.

### WHAT I AM TRYING

I am trying to make a profile view page. I am able to fetch all details from my sqlite database but i am not able to display my profile picture.

### TABLE STRUCTURE

```
    **username|landline|mobile|email|profilepicture**

         john |xxxxxxxx|xxxxxx|x@x.x|blob
```

### WHAT I TRIED

```
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM profile";
  $query = $db->query($sql);
  while($row = $query->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC) ){
  echo "NAME = ". $row['user_name'] . "<br/>";
  echo "LANDLINE = ". $row['user_landline'] ."<br/>";
  echo "MOBILE = ". $row['user_mobile'] ."<br/>";
  echo "EMAIL =  ".$row['user_email'] ."<br/>";
  header('Content-Type: image/png');
  echo $row['user_profile_picture'];
  }


  <html>
  <img src='profile.php?imgid=<?php echo $row['user_profile_picture'];?>'/>
  </html>
```

But the image dosenot show and also the rest of the data dosenot display when i put`header('Content-Type: image/png');`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an image.php:

```
<?php 
$sql = "SELECT user_profile_picture FROM profile WHERE id = " . $_GET['id'];
$query = $db->query($sql);
$row = $query->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC);

header('Content-Type: image/png');
echo $row['user_profile_picture'];
```

In profile.php:

```
<img src='image.php?id=<?php echo $row['id'];?>'/>
```

Comment: <img src='image.php?id=<?php echo $row['id'];?>'/> what does this mean. mainly what is id

Comment: I assume you have an id column (a primary key) in your table.

Comment: is this only support if image is png?

Comment: Nope, you can also store the image type in the db during upload.